# htaccess does not protect against download

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have create a website in my localhost using php and i put a htaccess file within my picture folder to prevent direct access to the file through the browser. in htaccess i put this *Deny from All* to protect my picture folder, it does prevent me from accessing the file in the folder if i type the direct link to the file in my browser but when i use php force download and set the path to the folder and the file name my computer could still download it. how can i prevent this from happening??

this is the php code

```
<?php
 $path="picture/check/";
                  $filename = "checks.png";
                  $actualfilename=$path.$filename;
                  $fakefilename="checks.png";
                  $num = 1;
                   if( $num == 1 ){
                        @readfile($actualfilename);
                        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fakefilename . '"');
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actualfilename));
                        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                        exit;
}
```

and the folder is located in this folder 
from website experiment 1

```
htdocs/experiment1/index.php/picture/checks.png
```

i can download checks.png using the code above if i put it in the index.php

but i could still download the check.png even from a different folder
`htdocs/downloads.php` (it contains the php folder above but with `path:/experiment1/picture/checks.png`)

this mean that when my website is online people could just create a php file and then he/she can give download the file in picture folder if they know the path to the actual file. i want to know how i can prevent this from happening i have tried using htaccess command `Deny from all` but it does not block php file from downloading it only block access if put the link in the browser please help its important

Comment: `but when i use php force download and set the path to the folder and the file name`  Please give us an example for this.

Comment: hi viktor i have edited my question please look at it one more time.